# Does this "symmetric" inequality holds?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples, quadratics, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $\sigma_1\le\sigma_2,\sigma_1^*<\sigma_2^*$ be positive  real numbers and suppose that $\sigma_1 \sigma_2=\sigma_1^* \sigma_2^*$, and that $\sigma_1^*+\sigma_2^*=1$.

Is it true that
$$ 1-(\sigma_1+\sigma_2) \ge (\sigma_1^*)^2+(\sigma_2^*)^2-\sigma_1^*\sigma_1-\sigma_2^*\sigma_2 \,\,\,\,?$$

A more symmetric equivalent rewriting is

$$ 1-(\sigma_1+\sigma_2) \ge \sigma_1^*(\sigma_1^*-\sigma_1)+\sigma_2^*(\sigma_2^*-\sigma_2).$$

From this form, one can easily deduce that equality holds in the extreme case where $\sigma_1+\sigma_2=1=\sigma_1^*+\sigma_2^*$; indeed, in that case the LHS is zero. Since the sum and the product of $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ $\sigma_1^*,\sigma_2^*$ are now identical, it follows that they are the same up to a permutation $1 \iff 2$. Since we have fixed their order in advance, we must have $\sigma_i=\sigma_i^*$, so the RHS also vanishes.

Comment: Do you also want $ \sigma_ 1 \leq \sigma_1 ^*$?

Comment: No, I don't want to assume that at the moment. Do you think that without this assumption, the claim has no chance to stand? (Or perhaps you have a proof when this additional assumption does hold?).

Comment: There are various instances that the inequality doesn't hold. I was just playing around with values to see what I could get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong. Try $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=\frac{1}{3},$ $\sigma_1^*=\frac{3-\sqrt5}{6}$ and $\sigma_2^*=\frac{3+\sqrt5}{6}$

But for $\sigma_1+\sigma_2\geq4\sigma_1\sigma_2$ the reversed inequality is true.

Indeed, let $\sigma_1=a$, $\sigma_2=b$, where $b\geq a>0$ and $a+b\geq4ab$.

Thus, $\sigma_1^*$ and $\sigma_2^*$ are roots of the equation:
$$x^2-x+ab=0,$$ which gives
$$\sigma_1^*=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4ab}}{2}$$ and $$\sigma_2^*=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4ab}}{2}.$$
Id est, we need to prove that:
$$1-a-b+a\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4ab}}{2}+b\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4ab}}{2}\leq1-2ab$$ or
$$(b-a)\sqrt{1-4ab}\leq a+b-4ab$$ or
$$(a-b)^2(1-4ab)\leq(a+b-4ab)^2$$ or
$$ab(a+b-1)^2\geq0$$ and we are done!

Comment: OK, thanks. I now also think that it must be wrong, due to a scaling argument. Can you elaborate on what was your reasoning that it's wrong? (and also why the reversed inequality is true in the regime you have specified).

Comment: @Asaf Shachar I added something. See now.

Comment: Michael, for your condition, I had $\sigma_1 = 0.3, \sigma_2 = 0.8, \sigma_1^* = 0.4,  \sigma_2^* = 0.6$ which gave the original inequality.

Comment: @Calvin Lin I got: $-0.1\geq-0.08.$ Are you sure that it's true?

Comment: Oh yes, I missed the negative sign. Sorry.